# How to implement ajax in theme customizer

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In theme customizer I need to show a section by changing the control in another section, so I depend on ajax. First I created a jQuery script for testing purpose - I picked the control ID from inspector.

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'kc_enqueue_script');    
function kc_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('themecustomizer', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'js/theme-customizer.js', array('jquery'));
}
```

Inside *customizer.js* I wrote:

```
( function( $ ) {
    var test=$("#optin_typetop_barinput[type='radio']:checked").val();
    alert(test);
})
```

But I got `undefined` as result. Why this happen? Also when I check on the console in inspector it send another ajax request. If my method is totally wrong please tell a solution for doing ajax in theme customizer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to add `(jQuery)` at the end:

```
( function( $ ) {
    var test=$("#optin_typetop_barinput[type='radio']:checked").val();
    alert(test);
})(jQuery);
```

The one that you have done is an anonymous function without a handle. So it goes nowhere. By giving `(jQuery)` at the end, it executes the function too.

Comment: can you pls tell is their is any possible way to implement  ajax in theme customizer.that is i I need to  dynamically show a section by changing the control in another section.problem is when i change the control live preview ajax is running.so i cannot implement my ajax .

Comment: @soju You can use `$.ajax`.